# javascript radio button validation, works in chrome, not in IE

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have this code to check that one from each group of radio buttons has been selected before the user can submit the form. It works fine in chrome, but in IE it always asks the user to answer all questions, even when they have. How can I change this to work correctly in all browsers?

```
<script>
function validate(){
  if (checkRadio("Radio1") && checkRadio("Radio2") && checkRadio("Radio3")){
  return true;
  }else{
    alert("Please answer all questions!");
  return false;
  }
}

function checkRadio(name){
  var radio = document.forms.myForm[name];
  for (var option in radio){
    if(radio[option].checked){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in `checkRadio()` --- you should not use a fast/enhanced `for` loop with an array.

Calling `for (var option in radio)` simply returns the name of the radio button group each time (e.g., "Radio1").

You must use the long form `for` loop:

http://jsfiddle.net/ugZL9/

```
function checkRadio(name) {
    var radio = document.forms.myForm[name];
    for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
        if (radio[i].checked) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that got it sorted!